# css table to grid with automatic column count

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm turning all my tables into grid-based divs due to how unrespnsive the tables are on mobile.

I've created a table that looks as such:

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-header">
      <span>Header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-header">
      <span>Header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-header">
      <span>Header</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell" v-for="(type, column) in columns">
      <span>Cell</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell" v-for="(type, column) in columns">
      <span>Cell</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell" v-for="(type, column) in columns">
      <span>Cell</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell" v-for="(type, column) in columns">
      <span>Cell</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell" v-for="(type, column) in columns">
      <span>Cell</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    .table
    {
        display: grid;
    }

    .table-row
    {
        display: contents;
    }

    .table-header, .table-cell {}

    .table-header {}
</style>
```

As you can see, it's a table with 3 rows:

- 1: contains 3 headers
- 2: contains 3 cells
- 3: contains 2 cells

Now, I've tried atleast 40 different combinations of grid-auto-flow, grid-auto-column, grid-auto-row, grid-template-columns - but for the love of me, I can't make **the grid have n columns, where n = amount of headers** - can this only be done using javascript?

Comment: At least, you have to add running code snippet so that we can see the current result. Including css as well.

Comment: @O.o Done, althought I've removed what was in the CSS when it didn't work out - the key thing is the last phrase of my question.

Comment: Seems like one solution is to use CSS variables, but I would prefer to refrain from using style="--columnCount: 5;" in HTML.